# WPF Grouping a DataGrid nested in databound tabs

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, grouping

I need to apply grouping to rows in a `DataGrid` that is nested in a `TabControl`. Both the `DataGrid` and the `TabControl` are databound.  The outermost control is bound to a ViewModel that exposes a collection of pages that is bound to the `TabControl`. Each page exposes a collection of lines that is bound to the `Grid`.

I am tried to follow patterns like [this one from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826038/wpf-datagrid-grouping-does-not-show-up-due-to-binding-error) and [this one from C-SharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/548/Default.aspx).  I'm not married to these, so if there is a better pattern ([as this post seems to indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021198/mvvm-what-part-of-pattern-responsible-for-grouping-of-datagrid)), I'm willing to go in another direction.

For now, I am not sure where to inject the definition of the `PropertyGroupDescription` and bind it to my desired `PropertyName`. I've tried doing it as a resource and directly as a `CollectionViewSource` on the `DataGrid`. But neither produced reasonable results.

This is what I have so far:

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.ViewInvoiceUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Grid Name="_grid" MinHeight="100">
```

> snipped for clarity...

```
<TabControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentInvoice.InvoicePages}" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
    Grid.Row="5" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="0,4,0,0" 
    Name="_invoicePageTabControl" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle />
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid 
                    Name="_invoiceLineGrid" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CanUserSortColumns="True"
                    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding InvoiceLines}" 
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                    RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
                    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=InvoiceLineGridVisibility}"
                    Initialized="_invoiceLineGrid_Initialized">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line Number" MinWidth="50"  Binding="{Binding InvoiceLineNumber}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" MinWidth="50" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Extended Cost" MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ExtendedCost}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Expander>
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I think I need to add something like:

```
<CollectionViewSource>
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DepartmentBillingCode" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

If I add the `CollectionViewSource` as a resource and change the `DataGrid` binding, there are no rows in the grid.
If I add the `CollectionViewSource` to the `DataGrid`, I get an exception: `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.` nested in `Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.`
But I don't see a `GroupDescription` or `PropertyGroupDescription` on `DataGrid.ItemSource`

So, I'm feeling lost now.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Георгий Ланец, thanks for the edit. It is nice to see old questions getting a little attention.

Comment: Paul, your welcome. I like to bring code to perfection. This is why I always pluck deadlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a possible answer.  I'm open to other people's interpretation.  Is this a good solution?

Applying an [SO post regarding what part of MVVM pattern is resonsible for grouping of DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021198/mvvm-what-part-of-pattern-responsible-for-grouping-of-datagrid), I went in search of a solution to generate a grouping in the ViewModel.  I found a simple example on [WpfTutorial.com](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

In my InvoicePageViewModel, I created a new property that creates a ListViewCollection from my List.  ListViewCollection allows me to add my own GroupDescription as follows:

```
    public ListCollectionView GroupedInvoiceLines
    {
        get
        {
            ListCollectionView groupedLines = new ListCollectionView(InvoiceLines); // TODO should this be cached?

            groupedLines.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DepartmentBillingCode"));

            return groupedLines;
        }
    }
```

Then it was trivial to change the data binding on the DataGrid from InvoiceLines to GroupedInvoiceLines.

Comments? Questions?